# I changed post_type and now I receive 404 errors

Tags: custom-post-types, debug

I changed a custom post_type to a different name. Now when I view a single page with the post_type I receive a 404 page.

How do I debug? Is there a WP log I can view the functions call?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just try to update permalinks (i.e. Trigger a flush of the rewrite rules).

Comment: Reseting the permalinks from custom => default => custom fixed the issue.

Comment: Can you explain how to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Hi **@Christopher Altman:**

Long time, no talk!  Hope you and the folks at Matter are doing well.

When you say you changed the name of the post type, I assume you mean you did so within your theme's `functions.php` file within your call to the `register_post_type()?`  If so, did you also run a query in the `wp_posts` table to update the `post_type` field?  If not you need to run the following query assuming your database prefix is `'wp_'` and replacing `'new-type'` with `'old-type'` as appropriate *(I'm assuming you are familiar with where and how to runn a SQL query?):*

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_type='new-type' WHERE post_type='old-type'
```

Another situation is that you might be using the [**Redirection**](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/redirection/) plugin? If so, try disabling it as it is known to cause these kind of problems.

If neither of these if your situation, please give more specifics such as how you defined your custom post type (did you use a plugin) and what steps you took to change? Also show some of the URL paths that are failing.

Comment: Hey Mike, good to hear from you again, and congratulations on the diamond next to your name. We are about to launch an awesome WP powered site with Google Maps integration. 

I went through the steps above. Although the post_types were updated the pages would not resolve. Finally, I figured out the answer (which I did not see in the documentation), you need to reset the permalinks.

I use /%postname% for custom permalinks. I set permalinks back to the default, refreshed a page, then set permalinks to my custom configuration. That reset fixed my issue. Thank you for the insight.

Comment: @Christopher Altman - Ah yes, flushing permalinks. That's one of the things I've learned to do so much I often forget about it. Also, you might want to rethink using just /%postname%/ unless you will only ever have a tiny number of *"Pages" (posts where post_type='page')*, see: http://ottopress.com/2010/category-in-permalinks-considered-harmful/